# How to achieve Polish plurals with use of django?

Tags: python, django, internationalization, django-i18n

I want to make some i18n translation but not know how to do it with django.

For example I want do such translation PO file example):

```
#: mainwindow.cpp:127
#, kde-format
msgid "Time: %1 second"
msgid_plural "Time: %1 seconds"
msgstr[0] "Czas: %1 sekunda"
msgstr[1] "Czas: %1 sekundy"
msgstr[2] "Czas: %1 sekund"
```

With such plurals rules:

```
nplurals=3; plural=(n==1 ? 0 : n%10>=2 && n%10<=4 && (n%100<10 || n%100>=20) ? 1 : 2);
```

I found such function but it support rather English than Polish how to achieve it in django?

```
def ungettext(singular, plural, number):
    return real_ungettext(singular, plural, number)
```

Answer (score 5):

My <s>girlfriend</s> wife is Polish and after trying to learn Polish for 18 months, I'm going to say this is impossible. Just kidding, have you tried this?

https://code.google.com/p/django-pluralize-pl/

Comment: Polish is easier than Hungarian - be happy :)

Comment: Grammar is not difficult it is easier than in English and German but there is declension - in Polish you could speak words in mixed order no as strict grammar like in English - it is hardcore for English or German since not strict order. There is some more sounds that in many language it hard to learn pronunciation since wider number of sounds and tricky. Whatever in Polish your read what you write what is not possible in English now.